How to solve 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.' in Vite/React for Google login?
I'm using Vite/React on the frontend and I want to get the authorization code from Google so I can finish the rest of the login in the Django backend.
The issue I get is, when the Google login popup opens is that I'm greeted with multiple error messages:
client:232 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
client:232 Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.

I've tried a couple of different settings in my vite.config.js file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    headers: {
      'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin-allow-popups',
      'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp'
    }
  }
})

This is my App.jsx:
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

function App() {
  
  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: codeResponse => console.log(codeResponse),
    onError: codeResponse => console.error(codeResponse),
    flow: 'auth-code',
  });


  return (
    <button onClick={() => login()}>Google login</button>
  )
}
export default App;

When I try using same-origin for the Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy the errors don't show up but also nothing else gets printed to the console after completing the login flow (essentially, I don't get the authorization code).
I've seen this issue cropping up for many people but I haven't seen a Vite specific one, so I'm curious as to if anybody has been able to solve this recently. I'm using the @react-oauth/google package. This isn't a critical error as it doesn't stop the actual functionality but I'd still like to solve it if possible.

I've set up a custom solution to integrate Google OAuth, which solves the 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy' problem. Get inspired by my approach
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useGoogleScript = (clientId, redirectUri, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptId = "google-client-script";
    if (!document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.id = scriptId;

      script.onload = () => {
        window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: clientId,
          callback: callback,
          redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        });
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }, [clientId, redirectUri, callback]);
};

function App() {

  const handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {
    if (response?.credential) {
      console.log('response.credential', response.credential)
    } else {
     console.log('failed')
    }
  };

  const clientId =
    "TOKEN";
  const redirectUri = "REDIRECT_URI";

  useGoogleScript(clientId, redirectUri, handleCredentialResponse);

  const handleCustomSignIn = () => {
    window.google.accounts.id.prompt()
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Google Identity Services in React</h1>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={handleCustomSignIn}
        >
          Sign in with Google
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

vite config
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  //same origin policy

  plugins: [react()],
});

Here's a google doc https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#prompt_parent_id that you may find useful.
